# A case of a making-change (sort of). Find the minimal composition of weights

Tags: c, recursion, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

TLDR: (part 1) Need to print out the best composition of weights to reach a target weight. (part 2) Don't know what approach to choose. (part 3) Also, recursion is not my friend.

I am not asking for a solution, I am just looking for a direction.

PART 1 
Some text first.

The input to the program is:

- a number of weights
- weights themselves
- target weights I am supposed to compose

There always has to be a weight that = 1, so all the weights can be composed exactly.
I am supposed to print out the optimal composition of weights, for example

- number of weights: 4
- weights: 1, 3, 7, 10
- target weight: 4
- output: 2 x 7

PART 2

The first thing that came to my mind was the unbounded knapsack problem, where I would set all the values for weights to "1" and then I'd look for the lowest possible value in the knapsack. The problem is, my programming skills don't reach that level and my googling skills failed me when I wanted to find a fine article/code/video/whatever to understand it.

Then someone pointed out the making-change problem. The problem there is that it usually uses an array and I am expecting really large numbers, I cannot afford to alloc an array of size = target weight. Also, it seems to require quite a lot of magic if I want not only the lowest possible number of weights, but the exact counts.

My solution now, shall I?

1. sort the weights in descending order
2. count the number of weights yielded from the greedy algorithm
3. remove one biggest weight used and try to compose the weight without it
4. repeat 3 until I have removed all the "biggest weights" or the number of weights started to grow again

(for weights = 1, 3, 7, 10 and target = 14, greedy would give me 1 x 10 + 1 x 3 + 1 x 1, after the third step I would get (0 x 10 +) 2 x 7)

I got here. Only I need to repeat this not outside the recursive function (like I was doing until I realised it still doesn't give me the right results) but I need to move the loop into the recursive function.

PART 3

This is how parts of my code looks now:

```
 for ( i = 0; i < weights_cnt; i ++ )
    for ( j = 0; j <= weight / *(weights + i); j ++ )
    {
        *counter = 0;
        if ( (res = greedyMagicImproved(weights + i, weight / *(weights + i) - j, weight, counter, min)) == 0 || min > *counter ) break;
        else min = *counter;
    }
```

It's a mess, I know. (the first recursive function I've ever written, sorry for that)

```
int greedyMagicImproved (int * weights, int limit, int weight, int * counter, int min)
{
    if ( *counter > min ) return 0;
    else if ( weight % *weights == 0 )
    {
        printf ("%d * %d\n", limit, *weights);
        *counter += limit;
        return *counter;
    }
    else if ( weight == 0 ) return *counter;
    else if ( weight / *weights )
    {           
        printf ("%d * %d + ", limit, *weights);
        *counter += limit;
        return (greedyMagicImproved(weights + 1, (weight - *weights * limit) / *(weights + 1), (weight - *weights * limit) % *weights, counter, min));
    }
    else return greedyMagicImproved(weights + 1, weight / *(weights + 1), weight, counter, min);

    }
```

This one produces something like this:

```
Number of weights:
8
Actual weights of weights:
1 2 4 5 10 20 60 95
Weights to be composed:
124
GREEDY = 1 * 95 + 1 * 20 + 1 * 5 + 1 * 4
IMP = 1 * 95 + 1 * 20 + 1 * 5 + 1 * 4
2 * 60 + 1 * 4
6 * 20 + 1 * 4
... some more irrelevant results I'll deal with later
28
GREEDY = 1 * 20 + 1 * 5 + 1 * 2 + 1 * 1
IMP = 1 * 20 + 1 * 5 + 1 * 2 + 1 * 1
1 * 20 + 1 * 5 + 1 * 2 + 1 * 1
1 * 20 + 1 * 5 + 1 * 2 + 1 * 1
2 * 10 + 1 * 5 + 1 * 2 + 1 * 1
5 * 5 + 1 * 2 + 1 * 1
... some more results as well
```

While I get to see the correct result in the first case, I do not in the second.
So basically, my question is: Should I try to move the loop part into the recursion (and write it basically all over again because I have no idea how to do it) or should I go stealing/packing and making change?

Comment: Is this your dissertation?  So very long... zzz

Comment: Your game looks fun though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a DP formulation:

Let `w[i]`, `i=0,1,...p` be the coin weights and `f(t,i)` be the number of coins needed to hit target `t` using only `w[k]`, `k >= i`.  When there is no possible way to make change, then `f(t,i)` is infinite.  With this we know

```
f(t,i) = min_{n} [ n + f(t - n * w[i], i + 1)  ]
```

In English, to hit the target with the minimum of coins using only coins `i, i+1, ... p`, choose all possible quantities `n` of coin `i` and then use the same DP to make change for the remaining amount using only coins `i+1,i+2,...`, finally choosing the solution that produced the minimum.

The base cases are common sense.  For example `f(0,_) = 0`.  You don't need any coins to hit a target of zero.

If T is the problem target, then the answer will be f(T,0).

Since you don't want the answer, I'll let you convert this to code.  It's likely you'll get to answers faster if the weights are sorted in descending order.

Comment: Applied. Modified. Works. Thank you. :)